# Add line name near by line without crossing other elements

Tags: svg, d3.js, charts, amcharts

Need to draw labels like on picture. This chart drawn by svg (maybe used d3), how is it possible draw labels without crossing with each other and other lines ? Is it any d3 tools or maybe some algorithms ?

example:
https://www.highcharts.com/demo/highcharts/spline-irregular-time

[image]

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67483719/where-can-i-find-a-good-label-placement-algorithm-for-line-charts/67553048#67553048